# ASP.NET GridView second header row to span main header row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET GridView which has columns that look like this:

```
| Foo | Bar | Total1 | Total2 | Total3 |
```

Is it possible to create a header on two rows that looks like this?

```
|           |  Totals   |    
| Foo | Bar | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

The data in each row will remain unchanged as this is just to pretty up the header and decrease the horizontal space that the grid takes up.

The entire GridView is sortable in case that matters.  I don't intend for the added "Totals" spanning column to have any sort functionality.

**Edit:**

Based on one of the articles given below, I created a class which inherits from GridView and adds the second header row in.

```
namespace CustomControls
{
    public class TwoHeadedGridView : GridView
    {
        protected Table InnerTable
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.HasControls())
                {
                    return (Table)this.Controls[0];
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDataBound(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDataBound(e);
            this.CreateSecondHeader();
        }

        private void CreateSecondHeader()
        {
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            TableCell left = new TableHeaderCell();
            left.ColumnSpan = 3;
            row.Cells.Add(left);

            TableCell totals = new TableHeaderCell();
            totals.ColumnSpan = this.Columns.Count - 3;
            totals.Text = "Totals";
            row.Cells.Add(totals);

            this.InnerTable.Rows.AddAt(0, row);
        }
    }
}
```

In case you are new to ASP.NET like I am, I should also point out that you need to:

1) Register your class by adding a line like this to your web form:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="foo" NameSpace="CustomControls" Assembly="__code"%>
```

2) Change asp:GridView in your previous markup to foo:TwoHeadedGridView.  Don't forget the closing tag.

**Another edit:**

You can also do this without creating a custom class.

Simply add an event handler for the DataBound event of your grid like this:

```
protected void gvOrganisms_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;

    if (grid != null)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, -1,
            DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        TableCell left = new TableHeaderCell();
        left.ColumnSpan = 3;
        row.Cells.Add(left);

        TableCell totals = new TableHeaderCell();
        totals.ColumnSpan = grid.Columns.Count - 3;
        totals.Text = "Totals";
        row.Cells.Add(totals);

        Table t = grid.Controls[0] as Table;
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.Rows.AddAt(0, row);
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of the custom control is that you can see the extra header row on the design view of your web form.  The event handler method is a bit simpler, though.

Comment: the updated answer has helped me alot, thank you for taking the time to document it

Comment: Same here - thanks for filling in the blanks

Comment: Note - I found I had to add `row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader` for the code to work without error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100201202857/http://blogs.msdn.com/mattdotson/articles/541795.aspx) should point you in the right direction. You can programmatically create the row and add it to the collection at position 0.

Comment: Thanks!  I used that link to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 13):

I took the accepted answer approach, but added the header to the existing GridView instead of a custom inherited GridView.

After I bind my GridView, I do the following:

```
/*Create header row above generated header row*/

//create row    
GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

//spanned cell that will span the columns I don't want to give the additional header 
TableCell left = new TableHeaderCell();
left.ColumnSpan = 6;
row.Cells.Add(left);

//spanned cell that will span the columns i want to give the additional header
TableCell totals = new TableHeaderCell();
totals.ColumnSpan = myGridView.Columns.Count - 3;
totals.Text = "Additional Header";
row.Cells.Add(totals);

//Add the new row to the gridview as the master header row
//A table is the only Control (index[0]) in a GridView
((Table)myGridView.Controls[0]).Rows.AddAt(0, row);

/*fin*/
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Note for those who choose to use RowDataBound Method in VB.NET

If you end up with too many extra header rows popping up, add an If Statement that only proceeds if the gridview's header row is nothing (meaning it is the one currently being bound)

```
 If grid.HeaderRow Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a class which extends gridview then override the CreateRow method.

try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163612.aspx) as a starting point

Answer (score 1):

Add `t.EnableViewState = false;` after you add the row:

```
Dim t As Table = TryCast(grid.Controls(0), Table)
If t IsNot Nothing Then
    t.Rows.AddAt(0, row)
End If

t.EnableViewState = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333714/1060656

i created this solution example

To run in your local system will will need to create 2 files ( one for the control and one aspx) you can either do it one project or 2 projects.

1. GridViewPlus ==> Control class
2. GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows  ==> a collection to hold custom header class
3. CustomHeaderEventArgs  ==> Event Args when custom header row is created
4. aspx file ==> Test program

   ```
   public class GridViewPlus : GridView
   {

       public event EventHandler<CustomHeaderEventArgs> CustomHeaderTableCellCreated;

       private GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows _rows;

       public GridViewPlus() : base ()
       {
           _rows = new GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Allow Custom Headers
       /// </summary>
       public bool ShowCustomHeader { get; set; }


       [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
       [MergableProperty(false)]
       public GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows CustomHeaderRows
       {
           get {return  _rows; }

       }

       protected virtual void OnCustomHeaderTableCellCreated(CustomHeaderEventArgs e)
       {
           EventHandler<CustomHeaderEventArgs> handler = CustomHeaderTableCellCreated;

           // Event will be null if there are no subscribers
           if (handler != null)
           {
               // Use the () operator to raise the event.
               handler(this, e);
           }

       }

       protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {
           if (ShowCustomHeader && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) return;
           base.OnRowCreated(e);
       }


       protected override void PrepareControlHierarchy()
       {
           //Do not show the Gridview header if show custom header is ON
           if (ShowCustomHeader) this.ShowHeader = false;


           base.PrepareControlHierarchy();
           //Safety Check
           if (this.Controls.Count == 0)
               return;
           bool controlStyleCreated = this.ControlStyleCreated;
           Table table = (Table)this.Controls[0];

           int j = 0;
           if (CustomHeaderRows ==null )return ;

           foreach (TableRow tr in CustomHeaderRows)
           {
               OnCustomHeaderTableCellCreated(new CustomHeaderEventArgs(tr,j));
               table.Rows.AddAt(j, tr);
               tr.ApplyStyle(this.HeaderStyle);
               j++;
           }


       }
   }

   public class GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows : System.Collections.CollectionBase
   {
       public GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows()
       {
       }

       public void Add(TableRow aGridViewCustomRow)
       {
           List.Add(aGridViewCustomRow);
       }

       public void Remove(int index)
       {
           // Check to see if there is a widget at the supplied index.
           if (index > Count - 1 || index < 0)
           // If no widget exists, a messagebox is shown and the operation 
           // is cancelled.
           {
               throw (new Exception("Index not valid"));
           }
           else
           {
               List.RemoveAt(index);
           }
       }

       public TableRow Item(int Index)
       {
           // The appropriate item is retrieved from the List object and
           // explicitly cast to the Widget type, then returned to the 
           // caller.
           return (TableRow)List[Index];
       }

   }


   public class CustomHeaderEventArgs : EventArgs
   {
       public CustomHeaderEventArgs(TableRow tr ,int RowNumber  )
       {
           tRow = tr;
           _rownumber = RowNumber;
       }
       private TableRow tRow;
       private int _rownumber = 0;


       public int RowNumber { get { return _rownumber; } }

       public TableRow HeaderRow
       {
           get { return tRow; }
           set { tRow = value; }
       }


   }


   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Example1();
           GridViewExtension1.CustomHeaderTableCellCreated += new EventHandler<CustomHeaderEventArgs>(GridViewExtension1_CustomHeaderTableCellCreated);
       }

       void GridViewExtension1_CustomHeaderTableCellCreated(object sender, CustomHeaderEventArgs e)
       {
           TableRow tc = (TableRow)e.HeaderRow;

           tc.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
       }

       private void Example1()
       {
           System.Data.DataTable dtSample = new DataTable();
           DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Column1",typeof(string));
           DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Column2",typeof(string));
           DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Column3",typeof(string));
           DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Column4",typeof(string));
          // DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("Column5",typeof(string));
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc1);
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc2);
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc3);
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc4);
          // dtSample.Columns.Add(dc5);
           dtSample.AcceptChanges();

           for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
           {
               DataRow dr = dtSample.NewRow();

               for (int j = 0; j < dtSample.Columns.Count; j++)
               {
                   dr[j] = j;
               }
               dtSample.Rows.Add(dr);
           }
           dtSample.AcceptChanges();
           //GridViewExtension1.ShowHeader = false;
           GridViewExtension1.ShowCustomHeader = true;

           /*
            *=======================================================================
            *  |Row 1 Cell 1   |   Row 1 Col 2 (Span=2)        | Row 1 Col 3   |
            *  |               |                               |               |
            *=======================================================================             
            *  |Row 2 Cell 1   |               |               |               |
            *  |               |   Row 2 Col 2 | Row 2 Col 3   |Row 2 Col 4    |
            *=======================================================================
            * 
            * 
            * 
            * 
            * */

           // SO we have to make 2 header row as shown above

           TableRow TR1 = new TableRow();
           TableCell tcR1C1 = new TableCell();
           tcR1C1.Text = "Row 1 Cell 1";
           tcR1C1.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR1.Cells.Add(tcR1C1);       

           TableCell tcR1C2 = new TableCell();
           tcR1C2.Text = "Row 1 Cell 2";
           tcR1C2.ColumnSpan = 2;
           TR1.Cells.Add(tcR1C2);  

           TableCell tcR1C3 = new TableCell();
           tcR1C3.Text = "Row 1 Cell 3";
           tcR1C3.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR1.Cells.Add(tcR1C3);


           GridViewExtension1.CustomHeaderRows.Add(TR1);

           TableRow TR2 = new TableRow();
           TableCell tcR2C1 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C1.Text = "Row 2 Cell 1";
           tcR2C1.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C1);

           TableCell tcR2C2 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C2.Text = "Row 2 Cell 2";
           tcR2C2.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C2);

           TableCell tcR2C3 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C3.Text = "Row 2 Cell 3";
           tcR2C3.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C3);

           TableCell tcR2C4 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C4.Text = "Row 2 Cell 4";
           tcR2C4.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C4);

           GridViewExtension1.CustomHeaderRows.Add(TR2);


           GridViewExtension1.DataSource = dtSample;
           GridViewExtension1.DataBind();

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do a similar task but required clickable buttons inside the header - none of the above worked in that case as the event handlers were not wired up (due to the sequencing of the events). In the end i used the headertemplate tag in the appropriate templatefield of the grid view. The html looks a bit more bloated but the events remain intact with no additional code behind effort. For example

```
<asp:TemplateField >
             <HeaderTemplate>
               <div>
                <div style="text-align: center;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                          text
                   </div>
                    <div>
                     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Apply to all" ToolTip="Apply to all - Special Bolt On" CssClass="sub_button input_btn_5" OnClick="ApplyButton1_Click" />
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>....
```