# Add headers VB.net/asp.net gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I know this question was answered, in C# and I have been trying to convert and get it to work, but have not been succesful?

I would greatly appreciate if you helped

[image]

this is an image from that question, i want to do something similar.

here is the link
[ASP.NET GridView second header row to span main header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314736/asp-net-gridview-second-header-row-to-span-main-header-row)

```
Dim d As Date = Date.Today
        d = d.AddDays(-1)
        Label1.Text = d

        'connects to datawarehouse
        saocmd1.Connection = conn1
        conn1.Open()

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        'selects sql query
        'saocmd1.CommandText = MYQUERY"
        saoda1.Fill(saods1, "salesasoftable")

        Dim row As New GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)

        Dim left As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        left.ColumnSpan = 3
        row.Cells.Add(left)

        Dim totals As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        totals.ColumnSpan = gridview1.Columns.Count - 3
        totals.Text = "Totals"
        row.Cells.Add(totals)
```

my error

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Source Error: 


Line 54:        row.Cells.Add(totals)
Line 55: 
Line 56:        Dim t As Table = TryCast(gridview1.Controls(0), Table)
Line 57:        If t IsNot Nothing Then
Line 58:            t.Rows.AddAt(0, row)
```

The answer

```
Dim row As New GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)

'spanned cell that will span the columns I don't want to give the additional header 
Dim left As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
left.ColumnSpan = 6
row.Cells.Add(left)

'spanned cell that will span the columns i want to give the additional header
Dim totals As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
totals.ColumnSpan = myGridView.Columns.Count - 3
totals.Text = "Additional Header"
row.Cells.Add(totals)

'Add the new row to the gridview as the master header row
'A table is the only Control (index[0]) in a GridView
DirectCast(myGridView.Controls(0), Table).Rows.AddAt(0, row)
```

Comment: what question? Provide a link to the question.

Comment: @geoff I would forget to add the link.

Comment: What VB code have you tried?  Converting the C# in the provided example directly to VB should be simple enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET GridView second header row to span main header row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314736/asp-net-gridview-second-header-row-to-span-main-header-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it just seems that you are having trouble converting c# to vb.net. Here are 2 online converters that can help out.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

http://converter.telerik.com/

Or [tangible software](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html) has a converter that can convert entire projects, but note that it is not free.

Comment: That first one is my favorite converter for doing large conversions as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to  handle this on the RowCreated event. You would test the RowType being handled, and if it is the header, you then:

1. Clear the row cell(s) in question.
2. Adjust the Rowspan of the first cell to 2 (in the case of your image: Qty Shipped).
3. Remove the row cell immediately following (in the case of your image: Total Sales).
4. Create a new table to look like the one you want as shown.
5. Insert your new table into the row cell desired.

If you already have the solution you wish to use, but it's in C# and you can't convert it, try this tool: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/