# gridview merge column headers

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview and I want to merge the headers of column (n) and (n+1) into one so that the output will use colspan to show a single header for columns n and n+1. I've seen several ways to do it by googling for this technique but all seem to be rather cumbersome and verbose.

I was wondering if someone had come across an elegant a short solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this article "[Merge Two GridView Header columns in ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/129-merge-two-gridview-header-column-asp-net.aspx)"? It builds the header row as you see fit. When you do this, you'll have to explicitly build each header (i.e. if you're merging Customer First Name and Customer Last Name, you'll have to ensure you explicitly include Customer ID and Customer Address, etc. as required.)

```
protected void myGridView_ItemCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {   
         //custom header.
         GridView gvHeader = (GridView)sender;
         GridViewRow gvHeaderRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
         TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();

         // First column
         tc1.Text = "Merged Column1";
         tc1.ColumnSpan = 2;
         tc1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;               
         gvHeaderRow.Cells.Add(tc1);

         // Second  column    
         tc1 = new TableCell();
         tc1.Text = "Merged Column2";
         tc1.ColumnSpan = 2;
         gvHeaderRow.Cells.Add(tc1);
         //keep building as needed.
         gvHeader.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvHeaderRow);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i created this solution example

To run in your local system will will need to create 2 files ( one for the control and one aspx) you can either do it one project or 2 projects.

1. GridViewPlus ==> Control class
2. GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows  ==> a collection to hold custom header class
3. CustomHeaderEventArgs  ==> Event Args when custom header row is created
4. aspx file ==> Test program

   ```
   public class GridViewPlus : GridView
   {

       public event EventHandler<CustomHeaderEventArgs> CustomHeaderTableCellCreated;

       private GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows _rows;

       public GridViewPlus() : base ()
       {
           _rows = new GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Allow Custom Headers
       /// </summary>
       public bool ShowCustomHeader { get; set; }


       [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
       [MergableProperty(false)]
       public GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows CustomHeaderRows
       {
           get {return  _rows; }

       }

       protected virtual void OnCustomHeaderTableCellCreated(CustomHeaderEventArgs e)
       {
           EventHandler<CustomHeaderEventArgs> handler = CustomHeaderTableCellCreated;

           // Event will be null if there are no subscribers
           if (handler != null)
           {
               // Use the () operator to raise the event.
               handler(this, e);
           }

       }

       protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {
           if (ShowCustomHeader && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) return;
           base.OnRowCreated(e);
       }


       protected override void PrepareControlHierarchy()
       {
           //Do not show the Gridview header if show custom header is ON
           if (ShowCustomHeader) this.ShowHeader = false;


           base.PrepareControlHierarchy();
           //Safety Check
           if (this.Controls.Count == 0)
               return;
           bool controlStyleCreated = this.ControlStyleCreated;
           Table table = (Table)this.Controls[0];

           int j = 0;
           if (CustomHeaderRows ==null )return ;

           foreach (TableRow tr in CustomHeaderRows)
           {
               OnCustomHeaderTableCellCreated(new CustomHeaderEventArgs(tr,j));
               table.Rows.AddAt(j, tr);
               tr.ApplyStyle(this.HeaderStyle);
               j++;
           }


       }
   }

   public class GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows : System.Collections.CollectionBase
   {
       public GridViewPlusCustomHeaderRows()
       {
       }

       public void Add(TableRow aGridViewCustomRow)
       {
           List.Add(aGridViewCustomRow);
       }

       public void Remove(int index)
       {
           // Check to see if there is a widget at the supplied index.
           if (index > Count - 1 || index < 0)
           // If no widget exists, a messagebox is shown and the operation 
           // is cancelled.
           {
               throw (new Exception("Index not valid"));
           }
           else
           {
               List.RemoveAt(index);
           }
       }

       public TableRow Item(int Index)
       {
           // The appropriate item is retrieved from the List object and
           // explicitly cast to the Widget type, then returned to the 
           // caller.
           return (TableRow)List[Index];
       }

   }


   public class CustomHeaderEventArgs : EventArgs
   {
       public CustomHeaderEventArgs(TableRow tr ,int RowNumber  )
       {
           tRow = tr;
           _rownumber = RowNumber;
       }
       private TableRow tRow;
       private int _rownumber = 0;


       public int RowNumber { get { return _rownumber; } }

       public TableRow HeaderRow
       {
           get { return tRow; }
           set { tRow = value; }
       }


   }


   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Example1();
           GridViewExtension1.CustomHeaderTableCellCreated += new EventHandler<CustomHeaderEventArgs>(GridViewExtension1_CustomHeaderTableCellCreated);
       }

       void GridViewExtension1_CustomHeaderTableCellCreated(object sender, CustomHeaderEventArgs e)
       {
           TableRow tc = (TableRow)e.HeaderRow;

           tc.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
       }

       private void Example1()
       {
           System.Data.DataTable dtSample = new DataTable();
           DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Column1",typeof(string));
           DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Column2",typeof(string));
           DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Column3",typeof(string));
           DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Column4",typeof(string));
          // DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("Column5",typeof(string));
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc1);
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc2);
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc3);
           dtSample.Columns.Add(dc4);
          // dtSample.Columns.Add(dc5);
           dtSample.AcceptChanges();

           for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
           {
               DataRow dr = dtSample.NewRow();

               for (int j = 0; j < dtSample.Columns.Count; j++)
               {
                   dr[j] = j;
               }
               dtSample.Rows.Add(dr);
           }
           dtSample.AcceptChanges();
           //GridViewExtension1.ShowHeader = false;
           GridViewExtension1.ShowCustomHeader = true;

           /*
            *=======================================================================
            *  |Row 1 Cell 1   |   Row 1 Col 2 (Span=2)        | Row 1 Col 3   |
            *  |               |                               |               |
            *=======================================================================             
            *  |Row 2 Cell 1   |               |               |               |
            *  |               |   Row 2 Col 2 | Row 2 Col 3   |Row 2 Col 4    |
            *=======================================================================
            * 
            * 
            * 
            * 
            * */

           // SO we have to make 2 header row as shown above

           TableRow TR1 = new TableRow();
           TableCell tcR1C1 = new TableCell();
           tcR1C1.Text = "Row 1 Cell 1";
           tcR1C1.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR1.Cells.Add(tcR1C1);       

           TableCell tcR1C2 = new TableCell();
           tcR1C2.Text = "Row 1 Cell 2";
           tcR1C2.ColumnSpan = 2;
           TR1.Cells.Add(tcR1C2);  

           TableCell tcR1C3 = new TableCell();
           tcR1C3.Text = "Row 1 Cell 3";
           tcR1C3.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR1.Cells.Add(tcR1C3);


           GridViewExtension1.CustomHeaderRows.Add(TR1);

           TableRow TR2 = new TableRow();
           TableCell tcR2C1 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C1.Text = "Row 2 Cell 1";
           tcR2C1.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C1);

           TableCell tcR2C2 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C2.Text = "Row 2 Cell 2";
           tcR2C2.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C2);

           TableCell tcR2C3 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C3.Text = "Row 2 Cell 3";
           tcR2C3.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C3);

           TableCell tcR2C4 = new TableCell();
           tcR2C4.Text = "Row 2 Cell 4";
           tcR2C4.ColumnSpan = 1;
           TR2.Cells.Add(tcR2C4);

           GridViewExtension1.CustomHeaderRows.Add(TR2);


           GridViewExtension1.DataSource = dtSample;
           GridViewExtension1.DataBind();

       }
   }
   ```