# Show merge header in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show Merge header of grid view using C#+ASP.net as shown in my image bellow:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: [Have you tried to do some search](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+gridview+merge+cells+&oq=asp.net+gridview+merge+cells+&aqs=chrome..69i57.8378j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Here is same question

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073771/gridview-merge-column-headers/9333714][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073771/gridview-merge-column-headers/9333714

Comment: Take a look into these articles: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16049/Merge-Header-GridView-DataGrid and http://www.etechpulse.com/2013/07/c-merging-gridview-header-columnscells.html

Comment: Hi,aleksey.berezan yes I have but not able to create gridview header as I want.

Comment: hi,user2156093 your solution works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Row_Created event of grid view. In which you can set ColSpan and Row Span property of a Grid view

See the below sample code:

```
protected void grvMergeHeader_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Employee Information";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Joining Date";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        grvMergeHeader.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

    }
}
```

For more reference see the below link[merging grid view header here](http://www.etechpulse.com/2013/07/c-merging-gridview-header-columnscells.html)