# Add second header row to GridView BELOW already existing header row

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, code-behind

I'm trying to dynamically insert a 2nd header row at a GridView's OnRowCreated event. However, I can't seem to get the row to be inserted anywhere besides the first spot in the gridview's row index. The code below fails on the last line, where the header is actually added to the grid. Index out of bounds exception. How can I add this header row *below* the already existing header row? Help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
protected void gvwProd_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView gvw = (GridView)sender;

        GridViewRow HeaderRow = new GridViewRow(1, 1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Prod Comments - TS/LID";
        HeaderCell.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
        HeaderCell.Wrap = false;
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Materials Comments - TS/LD";
        HeaderCell.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 8;
        HeaderCell.Wrap = false;
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Plant Comments - TS/LID";
        HeaderCell.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 11;
        HeaderCell.Wrap = false;
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        gvw.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(1, HeaderRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is ASP.NET then you should tag is as such

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. You could try casting the GridView to a Table and access the .Rows method:

```
((Table)gvw.Controls[0]).Rows.AddAt(1, HeaderRow);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206372/1460225)