# How do I change a gridview row so it renders as a second header row in the html table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview bound to a datatable and want the gridview to render the first row as a header row (th not td) along with the normal column namnes being rendered as a header row. Currently I am trying to this here:

```
protected void SampleGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;
    grid.Rows[1].RowType = DataControlRowType.Header;
}
```

This isn't working. I am open to any solution for this problem including manipulating the DataTable, the grid view, or the underlying HTML table through javascript. I am a C# coder and VB.net looks like gibberish to me so I would appreciate code in C#.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The answers to this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314736/asp-net-gridview-second-header-row-to-span-main-header-row?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridView` control doesn't allow a second header by default.

Any means to add a second header would involve some hack.

Here are two blogs that show you how to do it:

[Real World GridView: Two Headed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2006/03/01/real-world-gridview-two-headed-grouping-gridviews.aspx)

[Dynamic Multiple Row Column Grid Header](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27824/Dynamic-Multiple-Row-Column-Grid-Header)

Another hack is setting the HeaderText of some column to a value like `</th></tr><tr><th>` And split the rows yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I had read those articles and hadn't thought they applied because I was doing something slightly different. You answer made me look at them again and think a bit more out of the box. I appreciate your time,